# one-line dataframe df.to_csv fails, flipping all the data

Tags: pandas, dataframe, csv

I'm using a dataframe to calculate a bunch of stuff, with results winding up in the SECOND-TO-LAST LINE of the df.

I need to append JUST THAT ONE LINE to a CSV file.

Instead of storing the labels across and data beneath, the thing continually puts labels in the first column, with the data in the second column.

Subsequent writes keep appending data DOWN - under the first column.

I'm using code like this:

```
if not os.path.isfile(csvFilePath):
    df.iloc[-2].to_csv(csvFilePath, mode='w', index=True, sep=';', header=True)
else:
    df.iloc[-2].to_csv(csvFilePath, mode='a', index=False, sep=';', header=False)
```

The "csv" file it produces looks like this (two iterations):

```
;2021-04-29 07:00:00
open;54408.26
high;54529.67
low;54300.0
close;54500.0
volume;180.44990968
ATR;648.08
RSI;41.2556049907123
ticker;54228.51
BidTarget_1;53012.42
Bdistance_1;1216.0
BidTarget_2;54031.94
BCOGdistance_2;197.0
AskTarget_1;54934.18
ACOGdistance_1;705.67
AskTarget_2;55494.92
ACOGdistance_2;1266.41
TotBid;207.34781091999974
TotAsk;199.80037382000046
AskBidRatio;0.96
54408.26
54529.67
54300.0
54500.0
180.44990968
648.08
41.2556049907123
54071.49
53011.46
1060.0
53665.5
406.0
54620.97
549.48
54398.77
327.28
208.08094453999973
186.65960602000038
0.9
```

I'm at a complete loss ...

Comment: Why not just use `df[['that_last_column']].to_csv(....)` ?

Comment: Thank you for the reply.
The entire problem is there is no 'that_last_column'.
The dataframe is organized 90 degrees from what the software is doing.
'close', 'volume','atr' .. .are SUPPOSED TO BE the column labels.

There's no way to get a digital grip on what is being handled as a column.
I've had to manually list the labels - which means any change to the structure will mean a full manual edit.
I've had to manually strip the cells into a long string, with manually inserted delimiters, using write() to a csv file to make it work.

This kind of thing is why I hate pandas.

Answer (score 1):

I start with a .csv that contains

```
hello, from, this, file
another, amazing, line, csv
save, this, line, data
last, line, of, file
```

where the second-to-last line is the desired output.

I think you can get what you want by using

```
import pandas
df = pandas.read_csv("myfile.csv", header=None)
df.iloc[-2].to_frame().transpose()
```

The trick is that `df.iloc[-2]` returns a Pandas Series. You can determine the datatype using

```
type(df.iloc[-2])
```

which returns `pandas.core.series.Series`. I'm not sure why the Pandas Series are oriented the way they are.

The Pandas Series can be converted back to a dataframe using `df.iloc[-2].to_frame()`, but the orientation is flipped 90 degrees (matching the Series orientation). To get back to the desired orientation, the transformation called `transpose` (flip about the diagonal) is needed.